# Magento 2.3.3 Missing content in admin panel

Tags: magento2, admin-panel, magento2.3.3

After updating to version 2.3.3 and set SSL URL
The content of several pages(cms pages/consumer/orders/cms blocks and more) is admin panel is missing
this is what I get:
[image]

After on  debug Error showing as: 
"this is the error I get: Access to XMLHttpRequest at '332092-1019808-1-raikfcquaxqncofqfm.stackpathdns.com/pub/static/…' from origin 'url.co.il' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field x-requested-with is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response. and solved now by remove Base URL for Static View Files. "

Any help?

Thanks

Comment: ON Debug mode and check this error or check in console error once.

Comment: this is the error I get:
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://332092-1019808-1-raikfcquaxqncofqfm.stackpathdns.com/pub/static/version1571165412/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/Magento_Ui/templates/collection.html' from origin 'https://www.url.co.il' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field x-requested-with is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

and solved now by remove Base URL for Static View Files.

Comment: You are running into CORS issues..This issue is not due Magento for this you need to make changes in Apache or nginx configuration file. You can contact your server provider for this.

Comment: below link will help you:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/blocked-by-cors-policy-the-access-control-allow-origin-mean-stack

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/23339

Comment: check this: https://crunchify.com/how-to-fix-access-control-allow-origin-issue-for-your-https-enabled-wordpress-site-and-maxcdn/

Comment: Is it solve your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running into CORS issues..This issue is not due to Magento for this you need to make changes in Apache or nginx configuration file. You can contact your server provider for this.
Or check below Links which will help you:

1. https://crunchify.com/how-to-fix-access-control-allow-origin-issue-for-your-https-enabled-wordpress-site-and-maxcdn/
2. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/blocked-by-cors-policy-the-access-control-allow-origin-mean-stack
3. https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/23339

Or try to add below code in .htaccess

```
<ifmodule mod_headers.c="">
   SetEnvIf Origin "^(.*\.domain\.com)$" ORIGIN_SUB_DOMAIN=$1
   Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "%{ORIGIN_SUB_DOMAIN}e" env=ORIGIN_SUB_DOMAIN
   Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods: "*"
   Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers: "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization"
</ifmodule>
```

I hope it will help you.